# How to get existing Android key hash Certificate fingerprint (SHA1)

Tags: android, hash, keytool

I am making an Android app and am using the Facebook SDK. I generated the *Android Key Hash* by executing:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

How can I retrieve the `Certificate fingerprint <SHA1>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After [a little research](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html), this worked for me:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%/.android/debug.keystore
```